# What do the various colors in LogCat signify?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-logcat

I Googled this and could not found a chart. Since the various Log possibilities are Verbose, Debug, Information, Warning,and Error, I have a couple of assumptions, but...:

Verbose = ?
Debug = ?
Information = ?
Warning = Yellow?
Error= Red?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

The letter colors in above diagram are the colors in which log appears

Comment: Although these icons don't display above LogCat to make this obvious seems odd to me.

Comment: what does verbose exactly mean?

Answer (score 9):

The filter buttons on the LogCat pane in Eclipse are colour-coded to match the colour of the messages, so:

Verbose - black

Debug   - blue

Info    - green

Warning - orange

Error   - red

Edit: a picture reference:

[image]

*picture from http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-2.gif*

Comment: @alextsc Thanks for inlining the picture for me.

Answer (score 1):

- Error = Red
- Warn = Yellow
- Info = Green
- Debug = Blue (I think)
- Verbose = No color