# intellij idea logcat colors

Tags: intellij-idea, logcat

is there fix for logcat color miss match in Intellij Idea. It should be colored  according to Log level, but it mixes them. I am using 12.0.4 version. and there is the screenshot: 
[1] http://imagebin.org/251551 "image".
I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and Oracle JDK java version "1.6.0_35".

Thank You!

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778850/what-do-the-various-colors-in-logcat-signify is the question and answer about colours in eclipse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5483068#5483068
This is apparently a bug. I have reported.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, click in turn:

> File > Settings >  [IDE Settings] Editor > Color & Fonts > Console
>   Colors

you will see the options, e.g

> Console standard output
>
> Console error output
>
> etc...

And then right click the icon like below to customize the color you like :)
[image]

Comment: I have got right settings there, but as you can see in the picture, there is different problem: Look at the first and the second line of the log got different log levels, but they are painted in same color. This is the problem.

Comment: You will have to restart IDE after creating new logcatTheme

Answer (score 1):

I think `NobodyElse` means this path

```
File > Settings > [IDE Settings] Editor > Color & Fonts > Android logcat
```

Comment: I have got right settings there, but as you can see in the picture, there is different problem: Look at the first and the second line of the log got different log levels, but they are painted in same color. This is the problem.